# In Vue, when sending data from the script area to the template area, is there a shorter way to do it other than using a function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am currently using:

```
<template>
..somecode
{{showEditFlag}}
</template>

<script>
export default{
 data: function() {
    return { showEditFlag };
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there something like:

```
<template>
..somecode
{{showEditFlag}}
</template>

<script>
export default{
showEditFlag
}
```

I feel like the way I'm doing it is using extraneous syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you need to return it, data(){return { showEditFlag } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vuejs Standards should assign your properties in data property and it should return function not direct object like the following

```
//good way
data(){
 return {
  showEditFlag:true
}}

//bad way
data:{
 showEditFlag:true
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it using arrow syntax:

```
data: () => ({ showEditFlag });
```

But otherwise, no, the data has to be returned.

It's also worth noting, `this` can't be used in this context as it isn't bound with arrow syntax.